# creating a wrapper for the ExecutorService invokeAll()

Tags: java

I'm working of this code sample:

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

Set<Callable<String>> callables = new HashSet<Callable<String>>();

callables.add(new Callable<String>() {
    public String call() throws Exception {
        return "Task 1";
    }
});
callables.add(new Callable<String>() {
    public String call() throws Exception {
        return "Task 2";
    }
});
callables.add(new Callable<String>() {
    public String call() throws Exception {
        return "Task 3";
    }
});

List<Future<String>> futures = executorService.invokeAll(callables);

for(Future<String> future : futures){
    System.out.println("future.get = " + future.get());
}

executorService.shutdown();
```

I am trying to write a wrapper class for this code that will work for a generic type and can be cast to String/int/etc when unwrapping.

The issue I'm having is passing the collection to the `invokeAll()` method. I'm having some trouble adding my custom activities to the callables set.

Ideally I like to be able to separate out my code so that I can call methods rather than declaring an inner class. Is there a way to declare a collection of objects which are to returned from my custom methods that can be passed to the `invokeAll()` method?

I am trying a few different collections but continually get:

```
The method invokeAll(Collection<? extends Callable<T>>) in the type ExecutorService is not applicable for the arguments (Collection<Object>)
```

Comment: Can you post the code you have so far? The one that results in this error?

Answer (score 2):

Because [`invokeAll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#invokeAll%28java.util.Collection%29) is a [Generic Method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/methods.html), you may need to use special syntax to indicate what they type of `T` is. The following call should clear up your error:

```
List<Future<String>> futures = executorService.<String>invokeAll(callables);
```

Although I have to say, I was able to run your example code as-is in a standalone program...

Normally, this is not an issue, but may become a problem if defining your collection using type inference (available starting in Java 7). For example, if you initialized your `Collection` in the way of:

```
Set<Callable<String>> callables = new HashSet<>();
```

it means the compiler might have to work a little harder to figure out the type of your collection (although this too worked for me). This may be especially true in your case since you claim you are trying to write a generic wrapper class. The trickiness of generic methods is almost certainly at play. You may also want to check out [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html) Java tutorial on Generic Methods.